# What is the lift coefficient and why is it important?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, projectile, lift

Why is it that there are numerous experiment on determining the lift coefficient of a tennis ball. Does the value have any use or show us anything about the ball?

Answer (score 2):

*What is the lift coefficient and why is it important?*

The lift, drag and gravity are the three forces that act upon a tennis ball (see the image).

> "(1) FD = 0.5CDρAv2
>
> (2) FL = 0.5CLρAv2
>
> (3) Fg = mg
>
> Where FD, FL and Fg are the drag, lift, and gravitational forces, CD and CL are the drag and lift coefficients, ρ is the density of air (ρ=1.21 kg/m3), A is the cross-sectional area of the ball (average of 0.0034 m2 for the balls tested), v is the ball speed, m the mass of the ball and g the acceleration due to gravity (9.8 m/s2)."
> Source: [Aerodynamic Drag and Lift in Tennis Shots](http://twu.tennis-warehouse.com/learning_center/aerodynamics2.php)

If the tennis ball does not spin then CL=0 and you do not care about lift because it will be zero. If the ball spins CL will have various values and the resulting lift force, FL, will change the trajectory of the ball with respect to the case when it does not spin.
It is important to find CL to know how much the lift force changes the trajectory of a ball.

[image: Aerodynamic Drag and Lift in Tennis Shots]
[Aerodynamic Drag and Lift in Tennis Shots](http://twu.tennis-warehouse.com/learning_center/aerodynamics2.php)